# A-frame: make <a-entity> fixed always "on screen"

Tags: position, aframe, fixed

On scene placed , what need to be always before user eyes even when camera rotated on 180 deg. (ui contorls always fixed)

using aframe-video-controls library (but not strict  related to q.)

```
<a-scene>
...
<a-entity camera look-controls position="0 -1 -5" size="3" rotation="0 90 35"  video-controls="src:#video" > 
</a-entity>  
...
</a-scene>
```

How to make this a-entity like-a fixed, so it needed Always before user eyes, 
whenever a-camera rotated.

this attrs. do its job not bad,
 but only before 1st camera 180 degree rotation move at any direction.

style fix, like: 
also do not work for a-frame cotrols (double checked).

If someone worked on implementing fixed UI for a-frame, please say is it possible for a-frame scene elements to be always fixed, and how?

Comment: Try putting the entity as a child of `a-camera`. The rotation and position of the camera should affect its children.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but when putting like camera child; they just dissapeared. Was tried both with camera look-controls and without them. Should try adjust position via js, on camera rotate callback

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's still relevant question, but here is what you can do:

1. Put your entity inside the camera tag as suggested in comments:

```
<a-entity camera> 
    <a-entity position="this position is relative to parent"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

2. The position of your fixed entity is relative to the position of parent (camera). Adjust this position carefully, put `0 0 0` to verify your entity is there.

In your case, I think the entity was just out of camera view and you can never see it as it moved along with the camera.

Good luck.